# Can I create something similar to isGranted in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

So basically I want to create something like `@IsGranted`.
I used `@IsGranted` on my application to access control to prevent a simple user from accessing an admin page for example.

On my entity, I have a boolean field called `is_Active`

- if it's true (1) then the user can use his account
- if it's false (0) then he gets redirected to an error page!

In this case, I am not going to test on the `Roles`field of the user but I am gonna test on the `is_Active` field **that's why** I can't use the  `@IsGranted`.

I created an error twig page `active.html.twig`
and I place it on templates folder, and I found myself FORCED to add those 2 lines on **every** controller function.

```
if ($this->getUser()->getIsActive()==false) {
     return $this->render('active.html.twig');}
```

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
 * @Route("/", name="user_index", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(UserRepository $userRepository): Response
{
    if ($this->getUser()->getIsActive()==false) {
        return $this->render('active.html.twig');}
            
    return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
        'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
    ]);
}
```

This is very heavy and bad to add this if statement on every function (I have +30 functions on the app)

Maybe I can create something similar to `@IsGranted` and use it on the annotation of each function instead?

Comment: Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: So you want to prevent inactive admin users from getting through?  Seems strange.  You could adjust User::getRoles not to return ROLE_ADMIN if they are not active.

Comment: @Cerad I like this idea. But the problem is when the user login he will get my custom  503 (acces denied) error page! while i want him to get my active.twig.html error page.

Comment: So inactive users are able to login?

Comment: yes they can login but an error page appear after they login, (your account is not active ) message + button to Logout

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why can't you use isGranted? It is a lot more powerful than just checking a role. And do you have to use annotations? You can use `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted()` as well.

Comment: On my questions I said: In this case, I am not going to test on the Roles field of the user but I am gonna test on the is_Active field that's why I can't use the @IsGranted .
I am already using the isGranted to test on the user roles (admin, user)
I want to create something like IsGranted to test on the user Is_active Field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep using @IsGranted with a custom voter. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter

Create new voter like in the documentation

```
public const ACTIVE = 'active';

protected function supports(string $attribute, $subject)
{
    return $attribute === self::ACTIVE;
}

protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();

    if ($user instanceof User && !$user->isActive()) {
        throw new InactiveUserException();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then you can create a listener for `InactiveUserException` and show what ever you want to the client.

In your controller you'll need to put `@IsGranted("active")` or `@Security(expression="is_granted('active')")` before the route method or controller

Answer (score 2):

I would use the authentication for this then you don't have to touch your controllers. You can check if they are logged in and active then they can view the content or if they fail auth then you can direct them to another route with your active.html.twig.

You can also just have this set on certain routes or all of them.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Sample Authenticator and set this just for your admin routes then you can have a normal authenticator without checking for an active user on the checkCredentials for all other routes.

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Twig\Environment;

class AdminAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    /** @var Environment */
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $password = $request->request->get('password');

        return $email && $password;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $password = $request->request->get('password');

        return [
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $email = $credentials['email'];
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($email);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $password = $credentials['password'];
        if (!$this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                'Sorry, you\'ve entered an invalid username or password.'
            );
        }
        
        if (!$user->isActive()) {
            throw new NotActiveUserException(
                'This account is not active'
            );
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof NotActiveUserException) {

            // You should redirect here but you get the idea!
            $this->twig->render('active.html.twig');
        }
        
        // Do something else for any other failed auth
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new JsonResponse('success', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new JsonResponse('Not Authorized', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your security.yaml

```
    firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: user
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
```

Comment: I am interested for the reason for the downvote as in my understanding this is exactly what the authentication system is for. When you want to authorise large parts of your software then its better to write authentication to manage it so that you don't have to add arbitrary code to everyone of your controller methods/multiple controllers.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your answer. I am not really the one who downvote it, so I don't know the reason why ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @James Not the down voter either but I don't really think using the guard system works here.  Perhaps if you had posted some code it might help.  Of course I don't actually understand what the poster wants either.  However, perhaps you meant to suggest a Kernel Controller Event Listener which would fire right before the controller is called and could then be used to check the active property and redirect if need be.  But again, a bit of code helps keep the down voter away.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies, I added a code example of what I meant, so I hope it is clearer.